# Ultra instinct aura

Tags: dragon-ball-super

> Goku was hit by his own Genkidama and then he emerged in the ultra instinct state.

Beerus or whis said that he absorbed the energy of the Genkidama.
So is the aura being emitted from the ultra instinct or Genkidama energy?

Answer (score 1):

No. The aura being emitted is not because of the Spirit Bomb. Goku had to surpass his current limitations to survive the spirit bomb which resulted in him gaining the transformation. The heat emitted from his body was acting like an energy source which he gained from the spirit bomb.